# Delphi Appercept AWS SDK - SNS attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, amazon-sns

Trying to publish to an SNS topic with one or more attributes.
Without attributes all works fine, but after adding an attribute we get a 400 response with bad request.

below three ways we tried to add the attributes.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AWSOptions: IAWSOptions;
  SNS: ISNSClient;
  SNSRequest: ISNSPublishToTopicRequest;
  SNSResponse: ISNSPublishResponse;
  a: TSNSMessageAttributeValue;
begin

  AWSOptions := TAWSOptions.Create;
  with AWSOptions do
  begin
    Region := 'eu-west-1';
    AccessKeyId := '??????';
    SecretAccessKey := '??????';
  end;

  SNS := TSNSClient.Create(AWSOptions);
  SNSRequest := TSNSPublishToTopicRequest .Create(edt_ARN.Text, edt_Message.Text);


//  SNSRequest.MessageAttributes.AddString('test', 'testvalue');


//  SNSRequest.MessageAttributes.AddOrSetValue('test', TSNSMessageAttributeValue.Create('String', 'testvalue'));


//  a.Value := 'testvalue';
//  a.DataType := 'String';
//  SNSRequest.MessageAttributes.Add('test', a);



  SNSResponse := SNS.Publish(SNSRequest);

  ShowMessage(Format('Success: %s - Error: %s - Status: %d / %s - Message: %s' ,
                    [BoolToStr(SNSResponse.IsSuccessful),
                      BoolToStr(SNSResponse.IsError),
                      SNSResponse.StatusCode,
                      SNSResponse.StatusText,
                      SNSResponse.MessageId])
              );
end;
```

anyone an idea what is wrong here?
was looking to contact appercept directly as well, but they are not that reachable it seems.

Comment: I'm sorry you're having issues with our product. Your first line of support for our SDK bundled with RAD Studio Enterprise is Embarcadero, and they should forward anything they can't answer to us. You're welcome to contact us directly at support@appercept.com with the details of which version you have installed with which version of Delphi, and I'm sure I can help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap this up. The version of the Appercept AWS SDK in use was not the latest version, and the issue was already fixed in a newer release.

As a reminder to all, always make sure you're on the latest version.

In the above example, the correct method to add message attributes is:

```
SNSRequest.MessageAttributes.AddString('test', 'testvalue');
```